# How to query an order using Google Checkout API?

Tags: paypal, google-api, payment-gateway, google-checkout

In Google Checkout, after POSTing a `checkout-shopping-cart`request, Google will send a notification containing a `serial-number` several times. I can use this `serial-number` to charge or query the order. If I miss this notification, is there any other API to query or charge the order?

Is it possible to get `googld-order-number` or to query the order without setting `API callback URL`? Because I think sometimes it is possible that our server might fail to process the incoming notification from Google.

P.S. PayPal will generate a `token` when a payment begin. I can query and charge an order with that corresponding `token`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Each `serial-number` represents a specific (type of) notification
- You then make a [Notification History Request](https://developers.google.com/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_XML_API_Notification_API#serial_number_notifications) to *obtain the data* the `serial-number` represents.

You can "replay" notifications sent to you if you store the `serial-number` (and then perform a Notification History Request).

- You charge orders using [Order Processing API](https://developers.google.com/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_XML_API_Processing#order_processing_api)
- You don't use `serial-number` for this API, you use Order numbers (`google-order-number`)
- You obtain the Order number from the data you (previously) requested - above, using Notification History Request and the `serial-number`

You can think of `serial-number` as "pointers" to some data (that you need to obtain).

Hth.

---

Update:

If your server fails for any reason, don't/it won't be able to, handshake [`notification-acknowledgement`](https://developers.google.com/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_XML_API_Notification_API#responding_to_notifications), and Google will resend (until you can properly handshake or when the retry attempts expire - I *believe* it's 14 days).

You can of course do things **manually** by obtaining order numbers in Seller Order Inbox and use it in your Notification History Request....but for any automation, it'll be via your API callback url....

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to get `googld-order-number` or to query the order without setting `API callback URL`? Because I think sometimes it is possible that our server might fail to process the incoming notification from Google.